# Unable to invoke a parent method in child component reactjs

Tags: reactjs

In my parent container I have a function which validates the input entered by users.

The parent render is having child component.

```
render()
 { 
    return (
        <div>
            <Child
                value={this.props.inputValue}                    
                onChange={this.update}
            />
        </div>
  }

      Child render
           <input
                value={this.props.inputValue}                    
                onChange={this.props.update}
            />
        </div>
```

The validate function is not being called at all. Can anyone advise of the mistake?

Comment: What is the issue in your code?

Answer (score 2):

You are passing prop name called `onChange` from parent to child. So in your child component that prop can be accessed as `this.props.onChange`. You need to call `this.props.onChange` instead `this.props.update` like below

```
<input
     value={this.props.inputValue}                    
     onChange={this.props.onChange}
/>
```

Here is the working sample you can check,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>React Hello World</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.0.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.0.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/jsx">
      class Parent extends React.Component {
          update() {
            console.log("I am changed");
          }

          render() {
              return (
                <div>
                    Hello World!
                    <Child onChange={this.update} />
                </div>
              )
          }
      }

      class Child extends React.Component {
        render() {
          return (<input type="text" name="test" defaultValue="" onChange={this.props.onChange}/>);
        }
      }

      ReactDOM.render(
        <Parent />, 
        document.getElementById("app")
      );
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is you have mismatched the prop names in child component, try with this

```
validate(input) {       
    let value = input.target.value; //parent validate fun
    }
render()
 { 
    return (
        <div>
            <InputCom
                value={this.props.inputValue}                    
                validateHandler={this.validate}
            />
        </div>
  }

      //Child render
           <input
                value={this.props.inputValue}                    
                onChange={this.props.validateHandler('your param')}
            />
        </div>
```